# what wrong ng-repeat is not working?

Tags: html, angularjs

Here HTML Code

```
<a ng-repeat="category in categoires">     
<h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
<hr>
<p>{{category.des}}</p>
</a>
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.categories = [{name : 'abc',des : 'abc desc'},{name: "xyz",des : "xyz desc"}];
```

What wrong in my code ?

Comment: Spelling categories wrong

Answer (score 3):

You have defined scope variable as **categories** but using it as **categoires**

Change like this,

```
<a ng-repeat="category in categories">     
<h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
<hr>
<p>{{category.des}}</p>
</a>
```

Comment: @ncklanka please mark as answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are 2 problems
1.spelling mistake of categories
2.Invalid Object Array

```
<a ng-repeat="category in categories">     
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>{{category.des}}</p>
</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.categories = [{name : 'abc',des : 'abc desc'},{name: 'xyz',des : 'xyz desc'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code `categoires` as `categories`

```
<a ng-repeat="category in categories">     
<h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
<hr>
<p>{{category.des}}</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @AmilaSampath

Answer (score 0):

> make changes in both view and controller

View

```
<a ng-repeat="category in categories">     
<h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
<hr>
<p>{{category.des}}</p>
</a>
```

controller

```
$scope.categories = [{name : 'abc',des : 'abc desc'},{name: 'xyz',des : 'xyz desc'}];
```

or

```
$scope.categories = [{name : "abc",des : "abc desc"},{name: "xyz",des : "xyz desc"}];
```